# How to invisible line in list view for android Honey comb

Tags: android

I m creating an app in that app i want to invisible this Mr. bla bla two line when i clicked on chat image.

any suggestion will be appriciate.

thanks in advance.

this is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/task_list_frag_list_message_layout"
  android:background="#EBEBEB"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:descendantFocusability ="blocksDescendants"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/task_list_text"
  android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
  >

   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_list_chat_persion1" 
    android:text="Mr. Test : " 
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/sky_blue_color"
    />
     <TextView android:textColor="@color/black_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_list_chat_text1" 
    android:text="A send you a data file kindly get it." 
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/task_list_chat_persion1" 
    />

     <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_list_chat_persion2" 
    android:text="Mr. me : " 
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/task_list_chat_persion1" 
    android:textColor="@color/sky_blue_color"
    />
     <TextView android:textColor="@color/black_color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_list_chat_text2" 
    android:text="I got the data file and i have some doubt in them" 
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/task_list_chat_persion1" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/task_list_chat_persion2" 
    />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

this two lines are ij relative latout.[image]

Comment: can i GONE or INVISIBLE whole relative layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this ...
just need to add onClick() event on chat image and then on clicking set visibility of TextView to invisible by code.

```
TextView _text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.task_list_chat_text);
        _text.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on chat button in the list view you should setTest="" blank for both remove it.
It may be solution of this problem.